# Current Voltage Curve of a motor

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, voltage-measurement, back-emf

I have a question that has been bugging me for a while. I have an 48 W EC-fan with nomimal Voltage 24 V (voltage range 16-30V). I wanted to plot the current-voltage line of the motor so I thought of using a laboratory power supply and apply different voltages and measure the current in the circuit and the voltage across the fan and that was it. Now, what I did is I et the supply to say 24 V and then connected the fan. The fan starts turning until it reaches its final speed. Of course as it turns faster and faster the voltage drops to say 17 V as the fan reaches its final speed. The current is 2 A. The power supply also shows 17 V. My question is then, what is the plot point for the I-V curve, 24V - 2A, or 17V - 2A?

What is the reason for the voltage drop? Is it the internal resistance of the power supply, the back EMF which substracts from the power supply voltage, or both?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your power supply has a problem.  If you set it to 24V then why it is supplying 17V?

Comment: Is the power supply current limiting? This is common on bench power supplies. When the supply hits it's maximum current, the voltage is turned down by the supply. You will only be able to get an accurate curve if your supply does not go into current limit mode.

Answer (score 1):

What you are measuring is the combined characteristics of the power supply, motor-control circuit, motor and load.

The power supply has a passive impedance and likely an active current limiting feature.

Brushless motors can not operate with a DC supply without an active control circuit that, in effect, changes the DC supply to AC. That circuit has an impedance and a current-limiting effect.

The motor itself has an impedance and a back EMF that affects the current.

The fan requires very little torque to turn at a low speed. As the speed increases the torque required to turn the motor increases as the square of the speed. Torque actually delivered by the motor is proportional to current.

Dynamically, the inertia of the load also has an effect. Torque = rotational moment of inertia X acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly your supply is in current limit; I've never seen a bench type power supply that lacked this feature.  If you can, increase the current limit setpoint, otherwise obtain a bigger supply.

To answer your question, the plot point would be 2A at 17V, where the fan speed has reached equilibrium.  For a fan load, power will increase with approximately the cube of the speed, so you might expect it to draw around 4A at 24V.